# Read XML files in deployed app to Windows Store

Tags: c#, xml, windows-store-apps, windows-store

I have a simple service which let me read XML file.

```
public class SetService : ISetService
{
    private const string FilesPath = "Data/Sets.xml";
    private string xmlPath = Path.Combine(Package.Current.InstalledLocation.Path, FilesPath);

    public async Task<IList<Set>> GetAll()
    {
        XDocument loadedData = XDocument.Load(xmlPath);

        var data = from query in loadedData.Descendants("set")
                   select new Set
                   {
                       Id = (int)query.Element("id"),
                       Name = (string)query.Element("name"),
                       IsActive = (bool)query.Element("isactive"),
                       IsPassed = (bool)query.Element("ispassed"),
                   };

        return (IList<Set>)data.ToList();
    }
}
```

Everything works fine when I am using this method, on my local machine or on emulator provided with Microsoft Visual Studio 2013 but after I published this app to the Windows Store I am not able to see these data from XML files.
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: do you provide this `Data/Sets.xml` in your xap (if it is xap, not sure...)?

Comment: how to check it? I can see this file bin/Debug/AppX/Data/Sets.xml but it is still on my local computer

Comment: check properties of `Sets.xml` file in VS solution explorer, especially `Build Action` property [[For reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0c6xyb66%28v=vs.90%29.aspx)].

Comment: @har07 I set Copy Always for each file, upload it to the Store and nothing changed, still there is no data from these XML files. Any idea?

Comment: Did you try advancing the folder to 'Data' before reading the file using GetFolderAsync?

Comment: Wow it was almost 1,5 year ago I can't remember how I solved it ;/